# How to know if this is single.php or single-xyz.php ? I want display metabox on specific templates

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm creating a metabox for specific pages like single-xyz.php in wordpress admin. But it's showing on all single.php posts. I want to show the metabox only on single-xyz.php. I tried to solve it, but I stuck on it and don't know how to. Can someone help me?

```
add_action("admin_init", "featured_box_init");
function featured_box_init(){
    if (is_single('productbox')) {
        add_meta_box("featuredBox", "Product Area", "featuredBox", "post", "normal", "high");
    }
```